# I use Spring Security and a JWT token. It is not possible to apply the admin role in its rights

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Here is the configuration class where I distribute access according to roles:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;
   private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

   private static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = {
           "/v2/api-docs",
           "/swagger-resources/**",
           "/swagger-ui/**",
           "/webjars/**"
   };

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()

               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
               .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
               .antMatchers ("/user/**"). hasAnyRole ("USER", "ADMIN")
               .antMatchers("/user/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
               .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
               /* this disables session creation on Spring Security */
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
   }

   @Bean
   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
       final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
       return source;
   }
}
```

This is the controller class where I want to use the admin role:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Api( tags = "Users")
public class UserController {
   private final UserService userService;

   @DeleteMapping("/admin/{id}")
   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
   public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable @Min(1) int id) {
       userService.delete(id);
       return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
   }
```

If you delete in the configuration:

```
               .antMatchers ("/user/**"). hasAnyRole ("USER", "ADMIN")
               .antMatchers("/user/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Then the USER will also delete it. But if you leave this matching of roles, and make a request from the admin, then an error occurs when deleting the user.

```
{
 "timestamp": "2021-12-01T21:30:05.647+00:00",
 "status": 403,
 "error": "Forbidden",
 "message": "",
 "path": "/user/admin/2"
}
```

If you leave this annotation @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true), then again the same error and nothing can be deleted.
Are there any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Please state the problem more clearly. Are you trying to access the path /user/admin with USER role? Furthermore, what roles do you want exactly to match each endpoint?

Comment: I need only the admin to be able to use the controller method that I showed. But with the help of the user, I'm just checking: can someone other than the admin use this endpoint?